# Apache POI excel cell style update

Tags: java, apache-poi

Using Apache Poi I'm exporting my table to an excel sheet. I extended ExcelExport class, override the getCellStyle method and customized my cell styles.

Now what i want is when a user edits any cell in the excel document i want that cell to change its color, so anyone later reviewing the document can easily see what has been changed.

Is there way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution could be to add [conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/creating-conditional-formatting-formulas-HA001111661.aspx) to the cells use Apache POI's [HSSFSheetConditionalFormatting](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheetConditionalFormatting.html).

For example, if the cell value written by your program is 5 then your conditional formatting could set the cell background to yellow if the value wasn't equal to 5